# place an existing column at first position in mysql

Tags: mysql

please tell me how to place an existing column(contained values) at first position in mysql. Suppose i have a table EMP_DTLS and there are columns like NAME, SALARY, DOJ, DOB, EMAIL_ID, AND EMP_ID contains values in every columns. Now i want to place this EMP_ID at first position.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

I have tried the queries those are discussed here previously but those aren't working for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "first position"? You mean in a query? You can specify the order of the columns you're selecting: `SELECT emp_id, name, salary .....` etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_DTLS MODIFY COLUMN EMP_ID INT(10) FIRST
```

Just use the correct type,i used INT(10)